# AirConsole Simulator doesnt seem to work on Mac

Tags: airconsole

I tried following the [getting started guidebook](https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/getting_started), and I noticed that testing doesnt work. When I try with or the `/simulator`, it doesn't work for me.

I also tried just downloading the [premade pong project](https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/pong) made by airconsole and then testing it, but it doesn't work for me.

I tried by running the vscode live-server, I also tried running a local live server with npm live-server and with npm http-server.
None of those worked. I keep getting a broken page saying "() sent an invalid response."

I then tried uploading a project, and ofc, that worked, I managed to run the premade pong project... but if I have to test my game that way, development will be a lot harder.

It is also worth noting that when I go to https://www.airconsole.com/simulator/ and I just press "Load normal" using the pretyped pong URL...
I get "The web page at https://games.airconsole.com/pong/screen.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Did anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had an issue with forced HTTPS by Chrome and we came up with the following solution:

> Replace all the links of the simulator with http://http.airconsole.com

(We opened the `http.airconsole.com` subdomain for that reason a few months back)

Now, in your case, you should be able to play pong locally via:
`http://http.airconsole.com/simulator/#http://127.0.0.1:<your port>`

It should work with any server, we use `python3 -m http.server 8000` at Airconsole but you can really use any webserver.

We will update all of our docs accordingly very soon.